# Python __hash__ for equal value objects

Tags: python, hash, set

Say I have some Person entities and I want to know if one is in a list:

```
person in people?
```

I don't care what the 'object's ID' is, just that their properties are the same. So I put this in my base class:

```
# value comparison only
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__)

def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

But to be able to test for equality in sets, I also need to define **hash** So...

```
# sets use __hash__ for equality comparison
def __hash__(self):
    return (
        self.PersonID,
        self.FirstName,
        self.LastName,
        self.etc_etc...
    ).__hash__()
```

The problem is I don't want to list every property, and I don't want to modify the **hash** function every time the properties change.

So is it okay to do this?

```
# sets use __hash__ for equality comparison
def __hash__(self):
    values = tuple(self.__dict__.values())
    return hash(values)
```

Is this sane, and not *toooo* much of a performance penalty? In a web-app situation.

Thanks muchly.

Comment: Are there ever going to be unequal people with the same ID?

Comment: If 2 people have an ID of `None`, I want to compare their properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unordered nature of dictionaries means that `tuple(self.__dict__.values())` is prone to producing different results if the `dict`s happen to be ordered differently (which could happen, for example, if one had its attributes assigned in a different order).

Because your `values` are hashable, you could try this instead:

```
return hash(frozenset(self.__dict__.items()))
```

Alternatively, note that `__hash__` does not need to take everything into account because `__eq__` will still be used to verify equality when the hash values compare equal. Therefore, you can probably get away with

```
return hash(self.PersonID)
```

assuming `PersonID` is relatively unique across instances.

Comment: I want to do `person in people` where nobody has a PersonID yet. If there is a collision will the set comparison fall back to using `__eq__`?

Comment: The set comparison *always* uses `__eq__` after using `__hash__` to narrow down the search. This is how hash sets (like the Python `set`) are designed. The hash value is never intended to be a unique key.

Comment: You can, for example, be dumb and `return 4` from your hash function under all circumstances; it will affect the performance of set and dict operations (using your objects as keys), but will not affect the correctness of the program.

Comment: I see, so `hash(self.PersonID)` seems like the best performance/uniqueness tradeoff. Since in production, entities will usually have ID's. It's only in tests that they often don't. Thanks for your clear explanations nneonneo

Comment: @keeny: Forgot to mention: if you do expect `PersonID` to be `None` a lot, you could improve uniqueness using a cheap test like `hash(self.PersonID or self.LastName)`. This still hashes only one thing, but picks `LastName` when `PersonID` is a false value (e.g. `None`).

Comment: `self.__dict__.iteritems()` raised : `AttributeError("'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'")`

Comment: @ahmed_khan_89: ah, the answer was ten years old and written for Python 2. Updated now for Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using `__dict__` equality for `__eq__`, it'd be kind of dumb to not use the `__dict__` for `__hash__`. However, `values` gives an arbitrarily-ordered list that includes no information about which value corresponds to which attribute, so that code doesn't actually work. Instead, you could try

```
return hash(tuple(sorted(self.__dict__.viewitems())))
```

or

```
return hash(frozenset(self.__dict__.viewitems()))
```

both of which would remove ordering concerns and keep attribute name information.

Comment: `hash(sorted(...))` doesn't work since `sorted` returns an unhashable `list`.

Comment: @nneonneo: Dammit, I remember thinking about that, but then it slipped my mind while I was looking at something else. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the good question. You were doing exactly what I wanted to do. After reading these answers I did something similar but with a few differences.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, ", ".join(["{}={}".format(k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in sorted(self.__dict__)]))
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, type(self)) and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self == other
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(tuple(self.__dict__[k] for k in sorted(self.__dict__)))
```

I included the string method for extra credit, as I went and redid that after I thought through the hash method.

I found in another answer that `self.__eq__` should not be called directly, so I used `==` instead.

This hash uses a tuple of the values of the attributes of the class sorted by the keys. This will make sure that the ordering in the tuple is consistent. If you sorted the values instead the case were two attributes were swapped would have the same hash.